# OAuth2.0 calls and IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am writing an IOS SDK and allow users to implement Oauth2.0 flow in their ios app using my SDK.

I ask developers to create a custom url scheme that they pass in as a callback url to my webview controller.

the webview loads my site's oauth2.0 flow url. When the user finishes authenticating, mysite redirects to the developer's custom url scheme and closes itself (after sending the authorization  code to the developer's success callback function) after detecting that the current url matches the callback url the developer passed in.

Then from their server, the developer uses their application key and secret to exchange that authorization code for an access token.

Is that the right way to approach such a project?